# Recents not showing all file types on iMac

Tags: finder

I have my Recents showing in my sidebar. However, not all of the most recent files modified show up. For the past month, the only file types that show up are .pptx, .png. and .pdf. And not all of those appear. I also use Word, Excel, Adobe Illustrator and others but none of those are listed. I looked at an older post here from 2014 but it was never fully answered; at least the poster never responded that it worked. I am using macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.

Comment: 1) Recents only shows what you've allowed the Mac to include in Spotlight searches (see System Preferences->Spotlight).  Do the missing files show up in a regular Spotlight search?  BTW, my Recents shows everything, except what I've specifically excluding using System Preferences->Spotlight.
2) Sorry to ask, but is your Recents ordered according to Date Last Opened?

Comment: Thank you for your response, theorist. I checked my Spotlight settings and everything is checked including applications, PDF documents, etc. I do have them sorted by date newest first. I now see two Excel files listed but I have edited a couple more in the same timeframe. No Word files, no Adobe Illustrator files. The only consistently showing MS Office files that show are PowerPoint.. Random .png files, too. Anything else you can think of before I go to Apple directly?

Comment: But what about Spotlight search results?  Do the missing files show up there? [Here I'm not asking about what's checked in Preferences, I'm asking you to try a test search in Spotlight.] If they don't, that tells you it's a general Spotlight indexing problem, rather than a problem specific to Recents.